# Why is my http proxy middleware not working when i make a fetch call from a component other than App?

Tags: reactjs, proxy

This is how my setupProxy.js looks like.

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const context = [
    "/customers",
    "/login"
]

module.exports = function (app) {
    const appProxy = createProxyMiddleware(context,{
        target: 'https://localhost:7006',
        secure: false
    });

    app.use(appProxy);
};
```

This works perfectly when I try to make fetch calls from the App component but if I try to make fetch call from any other component , It sends the call to 3000 port instead of 7006.

I was not able to find any information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some issue with cache and I had to delete package-lock.json and restart the app to make it work.